# How can I run a script locally from a remote server such as www.mysite.com/script.sh?

Tags: script, remote

How can I run a script locally from a remote server such as www.mysite.com/script.sh

I tried:

```
. www.mysite.com/script.sh
```

and it does not work.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?  The website may just change that script to read "rm -rf *" or worse.

Comment: @Grant Because I can store a bunch of scripts on my web server and have access to them anywhere whenever I need them without having to download them or carry them around on a USB stick.

Comment: You have to download them. That's what getting the data from the server is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrote the script -- meaning that you're absolutely certain you know what it does -- you can just do this:

```
curl -s http://www.mysite.com/script.sh | sh
```

That uses `curl` to fetch the script and pipe it to the Bourne shell.  But in general, for anything you didn't actually write yourself, you should do what Grant suggested and *read it first*, because this is a great way to accidentally run malicious code.

So while this does, of course, "download" the script, it simply sends the data through the pipe rather than saving it to a file.

Answer (score 5):

```
wget http://www.whatever.com/script.sh
```

Then *read the script* to ensure it doesn't do anything malicious.

Then `chmod +x script.sh` and `./script.sh`

Comment: Or just `sh script.sh` without bothering with permissions.

Comment: Yes assuming they are all sh scripts.  Some could require other interpreters.